# How to upload jpeg file using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

The solutions I've found on SO haven't helped. I'm always getting the error '415 (Unsupported Media Type)'. But when I use Postman to upload a file to our server, it works. What am I doing wrong with this code?

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("", "<path-to-jpeg-file>");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "<api url>",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Bearer dP1K7UfZSko4vT3RyVH02...",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I've also read on SO that I have redundant content type declarations, so I tried it by removing "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and also tried removing "mimeType": "multipart/form-data" and still get the same error. And again, if I use Postman to upload the file, it works (so it's not a server problem). Postman also has a way to generate the code for ajax. I copied and pasted the generated code into my app and still get the same error. What is the proper way to upload a file (in this case, jpg) using ajax?

Comment: Setting `content-type` to form-urlencoded will be causing issues, I'd strongly suggest removing that. Also remove `crossDomain` and `mimeType`.

Comment: Also note that the second argument of `formData.append()` needs to be the binary data held in the file input control, not a string path.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan hmm, that's interesting, because I thought ajax can read the file. If I generate the code using Postman, the ajax points to a path and not the binary data.

Comment: That's solely a feature of Postman which is taking the file path, reading it's content and creating the request I the correct format for you. In the Ajax request you'll need to do all that manually

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so I read in the binary from the file and that didn't work. I was getting errors stating that the data is not a Blob. So I found a way to convert the file to a Blob and attached that to the data field and it still doesn't upload. I'm obviously not doing something right because postman works.

Comment: Your solution is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. You can just do `formData.append(referenceToFileControl.files[0])` - assuming there's only one file selected in the control.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there's no reference file control. I'm reading the file from a local database. That's why this was a bit of a struggle to figure out, because all examples were based on php, etc. In my case, I'm using file://path-to-file

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

---

## You aren't loading the file

> ```
> var form = new FormData();
> form.append("", "<path-to-jpeg-file>");
> ```

Here you:

1. Haven't given the data a name, so it won't appear in the request
2. You are trying to send a string path instead of the actual data

Replace that with:

```
var form = new FormData( document.getElementById("yourForm") );
```

Make sure the form includes an `<input type="file" name="something">`.

---

## You are breaking the information in the request needed to decode it

You are setting the Content-Type header using three different techniques:

---

This attempt is completely wrong. You aren't sending URL encoded data.

Remove this.

> ```
>   "headers": {
>     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
> ```

---

This is pretty wrong. You are sending multiparty data, but you are missing the mandatory `boundary` parameter.

Remove this too.

> ```
>   "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
> ```

---

This is correct. You are telling jQuery not to set a contentType at all which allows XMLHttpRequest to extrapolate it from the FormData object.

Keep only this one.

> ```
>   "contentType": false,
> ```

---

All this assumes that the server is expecting a POST request with a multipart body.

You haven't shown us the details of the request you are successfully making with Postman or the documentation for the API.

Comment: Ok so I'm not reading the file from an element, I'm reading it from a local database. So the only thing that I have is a path. How would I read it in with just a path to the file? (I haven't done much client side web development)

Comment: I've made all the changes you recommended. Then started getting errors "data is not a blob", so figured out how to covert a file to a blob. It still doesn't work. The interesting thing is that the server response with 200 yet the image is never uploaded.

Comment: also, I'm not reading the file in from an element, I'm reading as a path e.g. 'file://my.jpeg'. When you say 'make sure the form include <input type="file" name="something">, where do you put that?

Comment: @u84six — You can't read from a path. It would be a massive security problem if you could. You can only read from a file input.

Comment: this is a cordova app, so reading a file from storage is acceptable. There's no file reference control in this app, that's why it took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several different variations of configs, different ways to read a file, and with a little help from the people on this page, I've finally got everything working. I hope this saves other people who aren't very familiar with client-side web dev some time and trouble. I use Q promises here, but you can use any promise, and I'm sure there are a few defects (like error handling), but at least I've got file upload working!:

```
const readFile = (fileURI) => {
    return Q.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', fileURI);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = () => {
                const blob = xhr.response;
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    const data = reader.result.split(',').pop();
                    resolve(data);
                };

                reader.onerror = () => {
                    reject('error reading file');
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
                reject('unable to read image data');
            };

            xhr.send();
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e.message);
        }
    });
};

const uploadImage = (fileURI) => {
    readFile(fileURI)
    .then((data) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('base64', data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<endpoint url>',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            },
            data: formData,
            beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', this.auth);
            },
            success: (res) => {
                logger.info(`request success: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
            },
            error: (error) => {
                logger.info(`request unsuccessful: ${error.statusText}`);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        logger.info(`An error occurred: ${e}`);
    })
};
```

It took me a day and a half to figure this out! I'll fix the promises a bit now that I've got things working.